# show some kind of toolbox on hover

Tags: jquery

or something like that. I don't really know how i should call it what i'm looking for ( maybe you guys know the right term). But here's an image of what i mean:

[image]

As you might see, there's some kind of toolbox poped up at the second row. That only happens if you hover over the element.

My question is very simple ( probably not SO worthy, but my Google voodoo left me clueless... ), how do you properly call that ( so that i can use my Google skills with the right term. Or do you guys got an online example where i can look at it and use it for inspiration...

*---i gues i'm looking in the direction of an tooltip, but it looks like that isn't the right thing... ---*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using http://paulkinzett.github.io/toolbar/. This might suit your needs.

Comment: Awesome! That's where i was looking for! Thank you very much.

Comment: I know how this works here. It's just that I had to wait before i could accept. And in the mean time i got pulled away for an job...

Answer (score 0):

It seem like it's more a *vertical toolbar* than a tooltip, you can use the `show()` methode of jQuery which you call it using an event handler (in this case `hover()` )